# How is my understanding of upper/lower bounds of sets?

Tags: real-analysis

let L be the set of natural numbers [1,100]. Let M be the subset of L equal to all odd, natural numbers on the interval [1,100].
The greatest lower bound of M is 1, which is also the lower bound of L.
The least upper bound of M is 99, while the upper bound of L is 100.

Please let me know of any misunderstandings that I have. Thank you

Comment: You're correct.

Comment: And as a tip, if your set contains any upper (or lower) bound then this upper (or lower bound) is the supremum (or infimum) (Try to prove this).

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is flawless. Your bounds  for M are correct.